# X11 file manager in C, using Xlib and imlib2

Tags: c, x11

This is a still incomplete file manager for X11.  It can only navigate
through directories, select files (and do nothing with them), call a
script to open files, and call a script to produce and cache thumbnails (it uses the imlib2 library to render images).

Here is the git repository: https://github.com/phillbush/xfiles

To test it, do the following:

- First copy the scripts ./thumbnail to your $PATH (or write their
  complete path in the following step).
- Edit ./config.h, especially the four first items.  Set the `opener`
  field of the `config` structure to the name of the opener program (or
  to its complete path, on most linux, it's called xdg-open(1)).  Set
  `thumbnailer` to the thumbnailer script (there is one in the github repo).  Set `dirthumb_path` to the
  path to
  [`folder.png`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillbush/xfiles/master/folder.png)
  (the icon of a folder, included in the github repository).  And
  finally, set `filethumb_path` to the path to
  [`file.png`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phillbush/xfiles/master/file.png)
  (the icon of a file, included in the github repository).
- compile (there is a makefile on the github repository)

Thumbnailing is kinda hacky.
It processes one file thumbnail at a time. First it pipes, forks and execs the thumbnailer script with the given file as argument and add the file descriptor for standard output of this child process to the poll(2). When poll(2) gets the event of this file descriptor, it fgets(3) a line containing the path to the cached thumbnail, closes the file descriptor and wait(2)s for the child process to exit. And then repeats the process for the next file.
This approach is probably hacky and limited to my knowledge (which is not that great). Is there a better way to get thumbnails?
I will probably implement thumbnailing in a separate thread (after I learn pthreads, I have no knowledge in concurrent programming at all).

I'm also reading from stdin because I want to process commands (such as
"cd", "mkdir", etc) from stdin in a future version.

`config.h`:

```
static struct Config config = {
    .opener = "xdg-open",
    .thumbnailer = "thumbnail",
    .dirthumb_path = "",
    .filethumb_path = "",

    .font = "monospace:size=9,DejaVuSansMono:size=9",
    .background_color = "#000000",
    .foreground_color = "#FFFFFF",
    .selbackground_color = "#3465a4",
    .selforeground_color = "#FFFFFF",
    .scrollbackground_color = "#121212",
    .scrollforeground_color = "#707880",

    .thumbsize_pixels = 64, /* size of thumbnails and icons */
    .scroll_pixels = 12,    /* scroll bar width */
    .width_pixels = 600,    /* initial window width */
    .height_pixels = 460,   /* initial window height */
    .hide = 1,              /* whether to hide .* entries */
};
```

`xfiles.c`:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
#include "xfiles.h"

/* X11 constant values */
static struct DC dc;
static struct Ellipsis ellipsis;
static Display *dpy;
static Visual *visual;
static Window root;
static Colormap colormap;
static Atom atoms[ATOM_LAST];
static XrmDatabase xdb;
static int screen;
static int depth;

/* flags */
static int running = 1;         /* whether xfiles is running */

#include "config.h"

/* show usage and exit */
static void
usage(void)
{
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "usage: xfiles [-a] [-g geometry] [path]\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* check whether x is between a and b */
static int
between(int x, int a, int b)
{
    return a <= x && x <= b;
}

/* get maximum */
static int
max(int x, int y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

/* get minimum */
static int
min(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

/* call strdup checking for error; exit on error */
static char *
estrdup(const char *s)
{
    char *t;

    if ((t = strdup(s)) == NULL)
        err(1, "strdup");
    return t;
}

/* call malloc checking for error; exit on error */
static void *
emalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    return p;
}

/* call reallocarray checking for error; exit on error */
static void *
ereallocarray(void *ptr, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = reallocarray(ptr, nmemb, size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "reallocarray");
    return p;
}

/* call getcwd checking for error; exit on error */
static void
egetcwd(char *path, size_t size)
{
    if (getcwd(path, size) == NULL) {
        err(1, "getcwd");
    }
}

/* call pipe checking for error; exit on error */
static void
epipe(int fd[])
{
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        err(1, "pipe");
    }
}

/* call fork checking for error; exit on error */
static pid_t
efork(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        err(1, "fork");
    return pid;
}

/* call dup2 checking for error; exit on error */
static void
edup2(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    if (dup2(fd1, fd2) == -1)
        err(1, "dup2");
    close(fd1);
}

/* call execlp checking for error; exit on error */
static void
eexec(const char *cmd, const char *arg)
{
    if (execlp(cmd, cmd, arg, NULL) == -1) {
        err(1, "%s", cmd);
    }
}

/* set FD_CLOEXEC on file descriptor; exit on error */
static void
esetcloexec(int fd)
{
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) == -1) {
        err(1, "fcntl");
    }
}

/* get color from color string */
static void
ealloccolor(const char *s, XftColor *color)
{
    if(!XftColorAllocName(dpy, visual, colormap, s, color))
        errx(1, "could not allocate color: %s", s);
}

/* call chdir checking for error; print warning on error */
static int
wchdir(const char *path)
{
    if (chdir(path) == -1) {
        warn("%s", path);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* wrapper around XGrabPointer; e.g., used to grab pointer when scrolling */
static int
grabpointer(struct FM *fm, unsigned int evmask)
{
    return XGrabPointer(dpy, fm->win, True, evmask | ButtonReleaseMask,
                 GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None,
                 None, CurrentTime) == GrabSuccess ? 0 : -1;
}

/* ungrab pointer */
static void
ungrab(void)
{
    XUngrabPointer(dpy, CurrentTime);
}

/* parse color string */
static void
parsefonts(const char *s)
{
    const char *p;
    char buf[1024];
    size_t nfont = 0;

    dc.nfonts = 1;
    for (p = s; *p; p++)
        if (*p == ',')
            dc.nfonts++;

    if ((dc.fonts = calloc(dc.nfonts, sizeof *dc.fonts)) == NULL)
        err(1, "calloc");

    p = s;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        size_t i;

        i = 0;
        while (isspace(*p))
            p++;
        while (i < sizeof buf && *p != '\0' && *p != ',')
            buf[i++] = *p++;
        if (i >= sizeof buf)
            errx(1, "font name too long");
        if (*p == ',')
            p++;
        buf[i] = '\0';
        if (nfont == 0)
            if ((dc.pattern = FcNameParse((FcChar8 *)buf)) == NULL)
                errx(1, "the first font in the cache must be loaded from a font string");
        if ((dc.fonts[nfont++] = XftFontOpenName(dpy, screen, buf)) == NULL)
            errx(1, "could not load font");
    }
    dc.fonth = dc.fonts[0]->height;
}

/* parse geometry string, return *width and *height */
static void
parsegeometry(const char *str, int *width, int *height)
{
    int w, h;
    char *end;
    const char *s;

    s = str;
    w = strtol(s, &end, 10);
    if (w < 1 || w > INT_MAX || *s == '\0' || *end != 'x')
        goto error;
    s = end + 1;
    h = strtol(s, &end, 10);
    if (h < 1 || h > INT_MAX || *s == '\0' || *end != '\0')
        goto error;
    *width = w;
    *height = h;
error:
    return;
}

/* parse icon size string, return *size */
static void
parseiconsize(const char *str, int *size)
{
    int m, n;
    char *end;
    const char *s;

    s = str;
    m = strtol(s, &end, 10);
    if (m < 1 || m > INT_MAX || *s == '\0' || *end != 'x')
        goto error;
    s = end + 1;
    n = strtol(s, &end, 10);
    if (n < 1 || n > INT_MAX || *s == '\0' || *end != '\0')
        goto error;
    if (m != n)
        goto error;
    *size = m;
error:
    return;
}

/* parse path for directory and file icons */
static void
parseiconpath(const char *s, int size, const char **dir, const char **file)
{
    static char dirpath[PATH_MAX];
    static char filepath[PATH_MAX];

    if (s != NULL) {
        snprintf(dirpath, sizeof(dirpath), "%s/%dx%d/places/folder.png", s, size, size);
        snprintf(filepath, sizeof(filepath), "%s/%dx%d/mimetypes/unknown.png", s, size, size);
    }
    *dir = dirpath;
    *file = filepath;
}

/* get configuration from environment variables */
static void
parseenviron(void)
{
    char *s;

    if ((s = getenv("ICONSIZE")) != NULL)
        parseiconsize(s, &config.thumbsize_pixels);
    if ((s = getenv("ICONPATH")) != NULL)
        parseiconpath(s, config.thumbsize_pixels, &config.dirthumb_path, &config.filethumb_path);
    if ((s = getenv("OPENER")) != NULL)
        config.opener = s;
    if ((s = getenv("THUMBNAILER")) != NULL)
        config.thumbnailer = s;
}

/* get configuration from X resources */
static void
parseresources(void)
{
    XrmValue xval;
    long n;
    char *type;

    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.faceName", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.font = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.background", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.background_color = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.foreground", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.foreground_color = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.geometry", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        parsegeometry(xval.addr, &config.width_pixels, &config.height_pixels);
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.scrollbar.background", "XFiles.Scrollbar.background", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.scrollbackground_color = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.scrollbar.foreground", "XFiles.Scrollbar.foreground", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.scrollforeground_color = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.scrollbar.thickness", "XFiles.Scrollbar.thickness", &type, &xval) == True)
        if ((n = strtol(xval.addr, NULL, 10)) > 0)
            config.scroll_pixels = n;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.selbackground", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.selbackground_color = xval.addr;
    if (XrmGetResource(xdb, "xfiles.selforeground", "*", &type, &xval) == True)
        config.selforeground_color = xval.addr;
}

/* parse options; return argument (if given) or NULL */
static char *
parseoptions(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "ag:")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
            config.hide = !config.hide;
            break;
        case 'g':
            parsegeometry(optarg, &config.width_pixels, &config.height_pixels);
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    if (argc > 1)
        usage();
    else if (argc == 1)
        return *argv;
    return NULL;
}

/* compute number of rows and columns for visible entries */
static void
calcsize(struct FM *fm, int w, int h)
{
    if (w >= 0 && h >= 0) {
        fm->winw = max(w - config.scroll_pixels, 1);
        fm->winh = h;
    }
    fm->ncol = max(fm->winw / fm->entryw, 1);
    fm->nrow = fm->winh / fm->entryh + (fm->winh % fm->entryh ? 2 : 1);
    fm->x0 = max((fm->winw - fm->ncol * fm->entryw) / 2, 0);
    if (fm->main != None)
        XFreePixmap(dpy, fm->main);
    fm->main = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->winw, fm->nrow * fm->entryh, depth);
    if (fm->scroll != None)
        XFreePixmap(dpy, fm->scroll);
    fm->scroll = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, config.scroll_pixels, fm->winh, depth);
    fm->maxrow = fm->nentries / fm->ncol - fm->winh / fm->entryh + 1 + (fm->nentries % fm->ncol != 0);
    fm->maxrow = max(fm->maxrow, 1);
    fm->scrollh = max(fm->winh / fm->maxrow, 1);
}

/* get next utf8 char from s return its codepoint and set next_ret to pointer to end of character */
static FcChar32
getnextutf8char(const char *s, const char **next_ret)
{
    static const unsigned char utfbyte[] = {0x80, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0};
    static const unsigned char utfmask[] = {0xC0, 0x80, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8};
    static const FcChar32 utfmin[] = {0, 0x00,  0x80,  0x800,  0x10000};
    static const FcChar32 utfmax[] = {0, 0x7F, 0x7FF, 0xFFFF, 0x10FFFF};
    /* 0xFFFD is the replacement character, used to represent unknown characters */
    static const FcChar32 unknown = 0xFFFD;
    FcChar32 ucode;         /* FcChar32 type holds 32 bits */
    size_t usize = 0;       /* n' of bytes of the utf8 character */
    size_t i;

    *next_ret = s+1;

    /* get code of first byte of utf8 character */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof utfmask; i++) {
        if (((unsigned char)*s & utfmask[i]) == utfbyte[i]) {
            usize = i;
            ucode = (unsigned char)*s & ~utfmask[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    /* if first byte is a continuation byte or is not allowed, return unknown */
    if (i == sizeof utfmask || usize == 0)
        return unknown;

    /* check the other usize-1 bytes */
    s++;
    for (i = 1; i < usize; i++) {
        *next_ret = s+1;
        /* if byte is nul or is not a continuation byte, return unknown */
        if (*s == '\0' || ((unsigned char)*s & utfmask[0]) != utfbyte[0])
            return unknown;
        /* 6 is the number of relevant bits in the continuation byte */
        ucode = (ucode << 6) | ((unsigned char)*s & ~utfmask[0]);
        s++;
    }

    /* check if ucode is invalid or in utf-16 surrogate halves */
    if (!between(ucode, utfmin[usize], utfmax[usize]) || between(ucode, 0xD800, 0xDFFF))
        return unknown;

    return ucode;
}

/* get which font contains a given code point */
static XftFont *
getfontucode(FcChar32 ucode)
{
    FcCharSet *fccharset = NULL;
    FcPattern *fcpattern = NULL;
    FcPattern *match = NULL;
    XftFont *retfont = NULL;
    XftResult result;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < dc.nfonts; i++)
        if (XftCharExists(dpy, dc.fonts[i], ucode) == FcTrue)
            return dc.fonts[i];

    /* create a charset containing our code point */
    fccharset = FcCharSetCreate();
    FcCharSetAddChar(fccharset, ucode);

    /* create a pattern akin to the dc.pattern but containing our charset */
    if (fccharset) {
        fcpattern = FcPatternDuplicate(dc.pattern);
        FcPatternAddCharSet(fcpattern, FC_CHARSET, fccharset);
    }

    /* find pattern matching fcpattern */
    if (fcpattern) {
        FcConfigSubstitute(NULL, fcpattern, FcMatchPattern);
        FcDefaultSubstitute(fcpattern);
        match = XftFontMatch(dpy, screen, fcpattern, &result);
    }

    /* if found a pattern, open its font */
    if (match) {
        retfont = XftFontOpenPattern(dpy, match);
        if (retfont && XftCharExists(dpy, retfont, ucode) == FcTrue) {
            if ((dc.fonts = realloc(dc.fonts, dc.nfonts+1)) == NULL)
                err(1, "realloc");
            dc.fonts[dc.nfonts] = retfont;
            return dc.fonts[dc.nfonts++];
        } else {
            XftFontClose(dpy, retfont);
        }
    }

    /* in case no fount was found, return the first one */
    return dc.fonts[0];
}

/* return width of *s in pixels; draw *s into draw if draw != NULL */
static int
drawtext(XftDraw *draw, XftColor *color, int x, int y, int w, const char *text, size_t maxlen)
{
    XftFont *currfont;
    XGlyphInfo ext;
    FcChar32 ucode;
    const char *next, *origtext, *t;
    size_t len;
    int textwidth = 0;
    int texty;

    origtext = text;
    while (text < origtext + maxlen) {
        /* get the next unicode character and the first font that supports it */
        ucode = getnextutf8char(text, &next);
        currfont = getfontucode(ucode);

        /* compute the width of the glyph for that character on that font */
        len = next - text;
        XftTextExtentsUtf8(dpy, currfont, (XftChar8 *)text, len, &ext);
        t = text;
        if (w && textwidth + ext.xOff > w) {
            t = ellipsis.s;
            len = ellipsis.len;
            currfont = ellipsis.font;
            while (*next)
                next++;
            textwidth += ellipsis.width;
        }
        textwidth += ext.xOff;

        if (draw) {
            texty = y + (dc.fonth - (currfont->ascent + currfont->descent))/2 + currfont->ascent;
            XftDrawStringUtf8(draw, color, currfont, x, texty, (XftChar8 *)t, len);
            x += ext.xOff;
        }

        text = next;
    }
    return textwidth;
}

/* load image from file and scale it to size; return the image and its size */
static Imlib_Image
loadimg(const char *file, int size, int *width_ret, int *height_ret)
{
    Imlib_Image img;
    Imlib_Load_Error errcode;
    const char *errstr;
    int width;
    int height;

    img = imlib_load_image_with_error_return(file, &errcode);
    if (*file == '\0') {
        return NULL;
    } else if (img == NULL) {
        switch (errcode) {
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
            errstr = "file does not exist";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_FILE_IS_DIRECTORY:
            errstr = "file is directory";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED_TO_READ:
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED_TO_WRITE:
            errstr = "permission denied";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_NO_LOADER_FOR_FILE_FORMAT:
            errstr = "unknown file format";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PATH_TOO_LONG:
            errstr = "path too long";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PATH_COMPONENT_NON_EXISTANT:
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PATH_COMPONENT_NOT_DIRECTORY:
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_PATH_POINTS_OUTSIDE_ADDRESS_SPACE:
            errstr = "improper path";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_TOO_MANY_SYMBOLIC_LINKS:
            errstr = "too many symbolic links";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            errstr = "out of memory";
            break;
        case IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_OUT_OF_FILE_DESCRIPTORS:
            errstr = "out of file descriptors";
            break;
        default:
            errstr = "unknown error";
            break;
        }
        warnx("could not load image (%s): %s", errstr, file);
        return NULL;
    }
    imlib_context_set_image(img);
    width = imlib_image_get_width();
    height = imlib_image_get_height();
    if (width > height) {
        *width_ret = size;
        *height_ret = (height * size) / width;
    } else {
        *width_ret = (width * size) / height;
        *height_ret = size;
    }
    img = imlib_create_cropped_scaled_image(0, 0, width, height,
                                             *width_ret, *height_ret);
    return img;
}

/* draw thumbnail image on pixmaps; then free image */
static void
drawthumb(struct FM *fm, Imlib_Image img, struct Rect *thumb, Pixmap *pix)
{
    thumb->x = 0;
    thumb->y = 0;
    if (img == NULL)
        return;

    /* compute position of thumbnails */
    thumb->x = fm->thumbx + max((config.thumbsize_pixels - thumb->w) / 2, 0);
    thumb->y = fm->thumby + max((config.thumbsize_pixels - thumb->h) / 2, 0);

    /* clean pixmaps */
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.normal[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, pix[UNSEL], dc.gc, fm->thumbx, fm->thumby, config.thumbsize_pixels, config.thumbsize_pixels);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, pix[SEL], dc.gc, fm->thumbx - THUMBBORDER, fm->thumby - THUMBBORDER, config.thumbsize_pixels + 2 * THUMBBORDER, config.thumbsize_pixels + 2 * THUMBBORDER);

    /* draw border on sel pixmap around thumbnail */
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.select[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, pix[SEL], dc.gc, thumb->x - THUMBBORDER, thumb->y - THUMBBORDER, thumb->w + 2 * THUMBBORDER, thumb->h + 2 * THUMBBORDER);
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.normal[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, pix[SEL], dc.gc, thumb->x, thumb->y, thumb->w, thumb->h);

    /* draw thumbnail on both pixmaps */
    imlib_context_set_image(img);
    imlib_image_set_changes_on_disk();
    imlib_context_set_drawable(pix[UNSEL]);
    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(thumb->x, thumb->y);
    imlib_context_set_drawable(pix[SEL]);
    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(thumb->x, thumb->y);

    /* free image */
    imlib_free_image();
}

/* call sigaction on sig */
static void
initsignal(int sig, void (*handler)(int sig))
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if (sigaction(sig, &sa, 0) == -1) {
        err(1, "signal %d", sig);
    }
}

/* intern atoms */
static void
initatoms(void)
{
    char *atomnames[ATOM_LAST] = {
        [UTF8_STRING]                = "UTF8_STRING",
        [WM_DELETE_WINDOW]           = "WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
        [_NET_WM_NAME]               = "_NET_WM_NAME",
        [_NET_WM_PID]                = "_NET_WM_PID",
        [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE]        = "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE",
        [_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL] = "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL",
    };

    XInternAtoms(dpy, atomnames, ATOM_LAST, False, atoms);
}

/* initialize drawing context (colors and graphics context) */
static void
initdc(void)
{
    dc.gc = XCreateGC(dpy, root, 0, NULL);
    ealloccolor(config.background_color, &dc.normal[COLOR_BG]);
    ealloccolor(config.foreground_color, &dc.normal[COLOR_FG]);
    ealloccolor(config.selbackground_color, &dc.select[COLOR_BG]);
    ealloccolor(config.selforeground_color, &dc.select[COLOR_FG]);
    ealloccolor(config.scrollbackground_color, &dc.scroll[COLOR_BG]);
    ealloccolor(config.scrollforeground_color, &dc.scroll[COLOR_FG]);
    parsefonts(config.font);
}

/* create window and set its properties */
static void
initfm(struct FM *fm, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    XSetWindowAttributes swa;
    XClassHint classh;
    Imlib_Image fileimg;
    Imlib_Image dirimg;
    pid_t pid;

    fm->main = None;
    fm->scroll = None;
    fm->hist = fm->curr = NULL;
    fm->entries = NULL;
    fm->selected = NULL;
    fm->capacity = 0;
    fm->nentries = 0;
    fm->row = 0;
    fm->ydiff = 0;
    fm->entryw = config.thumbsize_pixels * 2;
    fm->entryh = config.thumbsize_pixels + 3 * dc.fonth + 2 * THUMBBORDER;
    fm->thumbx = config.thumbsize_pixels / 2;
    fm->thumby = dc.fonth / 2;
    fm->textw = fm->entryw - dc.fonth;
    fm->textx = dc.fonth / 2;
    fm->texty0 = dc.fonth / 2 + config.thumbsize_pixels + 2 * THUMBBORDER;
    fm->texty1 = fm->texty0 + dc.fonth;
    memset(&fm->dirrect, 0, sizeof(fm->dirrect));
    memset(&fm->filerect, 0, sizeof(fm->filerect));

    swa.background_pixel = dc.normal[COLOR_BG].pixel;
    swa.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | ButtonPressMask;
    fm->win = XCreateWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, config.width_pixels, config.height_pixels, 0,
                            CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent,
                            CWBackPixel | CWEventMask, &swa);

    classh.res_class = CLASS;
    classh.res_name = NULL;
    pid = getpid();
    XmbSetWMProperties(dpy, fm->win, TITLE, TITLE, argv, argc, NULL, NULL, &classh);
    XSetWMProtocols(dpy, fm->win, &atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW], 1);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, fm->win, atoms[_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE], XA_ATOM, 32,
                    PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&atoms[_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL], 1);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, fm->win, atoms[_NET_WM_PID], XA_CARDINAL, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *)&pid, 1);

    calcsize(fm, config.width_pixels, config.height_pixels);

    /* create and clean default thumbnails */
    fm->file[UNSEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    fm->file[SEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    fm->dir[UNSEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    fm->dir[SEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.normal[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->file[UNSEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->file[SEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->dir[UNSEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->dir[SEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh);

    /* draw default thumbnails */
    if (config.filethumb_path != NULL && config.filethumb_path[0] != '\0') {
        fileimg = loadimg(config.filethumb_path, config.thumbsize_pixels, &fm->filerect.w, &fm->filerect.h);
        drawthumb(fm, fileimg, &fm->filerect, fm->file);
    } else {
        warnx("could not find icon for files");
    }
    if (config.dirthumb_path != NULL && config.dirthumb_path[0] != '\0') {
        dirimg = loadimg(config.dirthumb_path, config.thumbsize_pixels, &fm->dirrect.w, &fm->dirrect.h);
        drawthumb(fm, dirimg, &fm->dirrect, fm->dir);
    } else {
        warnx("could not find icon for directories");
    }
}

/* compute width of ellipsis string */
static void
initellipsis(void)
{
    XGlyphInfo ext;
    FcChar32 ucode;
    const char *s;

    ellipsis.s = ELLIPSIS;
    ellipsis.len = strlen(ellipsis.s);
    ucode = getnextutf8char(ellipsis.s, &s);
    ellipsis.font = getfontucode(ucode);
    XftTextExtentsUtf8(dpy, ellipsis.font, (XftChar8 *)ellipsis.s, ellipsis.len, &ext);
    ellipsis.width = ext.xOff;
}

/* delete current cwd and previous from working directory history */
static void
delcwd(struct FM *fm)
{
    struct Histent *h, *tmp;

    if (fm->curr == NULL)
        return;
    h = fm->curr->next;
    while (h != NULL) {
        tmp = h;
        h = h->next;
        free(tmp->cwd);
        free(tmp);
    }
    fm->curr->next = NULL;
    fm->hist = fm->curr;
}

/* insert cwd into working directory history */
static void
addcwd(struct FM *fm, char *path) {
    struct Histent *h;

    delcwd(fm);
    h = emalloc(sizeof(*h));
    h->cwd = estrdup(path);
    h->next = NULL;
    h->prev = fm->hist;
    if (fm->hist)
        fm->hist->next = h;
    fm->curr = fm->hist = h;
}

/* select entries according to config.hide */
static int
direntselect(const struct dirent *dp)
{
    if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0)
        return 0;
    if (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
        return 1;
    if (config.hide && dp->d_name[0] == '.')
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

/* compare entries with strcoll, directories first */
static int
entrycompar(const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    struct Entry *a, *b;
    a = *(struct Entry **)ap;
    b = *(struct Entry **)bp;
    /* dotdot (parent directory) first */
    if (strcmp(a->name, "..") == 0)
        return -1;
    if (strcmp(b->name, "..") == 0)
        return 1;

    /* directories first */
    if (a->isdir && !b->isdir)
        return -1;
    if (b->isdir && !a->isdir)
        return 1;

    /* dotentries (hidden entries) first */
    if (a->name[0] == '.' && b->name[0] != '.')
        return -1;
    if (b->name[0] == '.' && a->name[0] != '.')
        return 1;
    return strcoll(a->name, b->name);
}

/* allocate entry */
static struct Entry *
allocentry(struct FM *fm, const char *name, int isdir)
{
    struct Entry *ent;

    ent = emalloc(sizeof *ent);
    ent->sprev = ent->snext = NULL;
    ent->pix[UNSEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    ent->pix[SEL] = XCreatePixmap(dpy, fm->win, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, depth);
    ent->issel = 0;
    ent->isdir = isdir;
    ent->drawn = 0;
    ent->name = estrdup(name);
    memset(ent->line, 0, sizeof(ent->line));
    if (ent->isdir) {
        ent->thumb = fm->dirrect;
        XCopyArea(dpy, fm->dir[UNSEL], ent->pix[UNSEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, 0, 0);
        XCopyArea(dpy, fm->dir[SEL], ent->pix[SEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, 0, 0);
    } else {
        ent->thumb = fm->filerect;
        XCopyArea(dpy, fm->file[UNSEL], ent->pix[UNSEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, 0, 0);
        XCopyArea(dpy, fm->file[SEL], ent->pix[SEL], dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, 0, 0);
    }
    return ent;
}

/* destroy entry */
static void
freeentries(struct FM *fm)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < fm->nentries; i++) {
        XFreePixmap(dpy, fm->entries[i]->pix[UNSEL]);
        XFreePixmap(dpy, fm->entries[i]->pix[SEL]);
        free(fm->entries[i]->name);
        free(fm->entries[i]);
    }
}

/* populate list of entries on fm; return -1 on error */
static void
listentries(struct FM *fm, int savecwd)
{
    struct dirent **array;
    struct stat sb;
    int i, n, isdir;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    egetcwd(path, sizeof(path));
    if (savecwd)
        addcwd(fm, path);
    if ((n = scandir(path, &array, direntselect, NULL)) == -1)
        err(1, "scandir");
    freeentries(fm);
    if (n > fm->capacity) {
        fm->entries = ereallocarray(fm->entries, n, sizeof(*fm->entries));
        fm->capacity = n;
    }
    fm->nentries = n;
    for (i = 0; i < fm->nentries; i++) {
        if (stat(array[i]->d_name, &sb) == -1) {
            warn("%s", path);
            isdir = 0;
        } else {
            isdir = S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode);
        }
        fm->entries[i] = allocentry(fm, array[i]->d_name, isdir);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    qsort(fm->entries, fm->nentries, sizeof(*fm->entries), entrycompar);
}

/* get index of entry from pointer position; return -1 if not found */
static int
getentry(struct FM *fm, int x, int y)
{
    struct Entry *ent;
    int i, n, w, h;

    if (x < fm->x0 || x >= fm->x0 + fm->ncol * fm->entryw)
        return -1;
    if (y < 0 || y >= fm->winh)
        return -1;
    x -= fm->x0;
    y += fm->ydiff;
    w = x / fm->entryw;
    h = y / fm->entryh;
    i = fm->row * fm->ncol + h * fm->ncol + w;
    n = min(fm->nentries, fm->row * fm->ncol + fm->nrow * fm->ncol);
    if (i < fm->row * fm->ncol || i >= n)
        return -1;
    x -= w * fm->entryw;
    y -= h * fm->entryh;
    ent = fm->entries[i];
    if ((x >= ent->thumb.x && x < ent->thumb.x + ent->thumb.w && y >= ent->thumb.y && y < ent->thumb.y + ent->thumb.h) ||
        (x >= ent->line[0].x && x < ent->line[0].x + ent->line[0].w && y >= fm->texty0 && y < fm->texty0 + dc.fonth) ||
        (x >= ent->line[1].x && x < ent->line[1].x + ent->line[1].w && y >= fm->texty1 && y < fm->texty1 + dc.fonth))
        return i;
    return -1;
}

/* copy entry pixmap into fm pixmap */
static void
copyentry(struct FM *fm, int i)
{
    Pixmap pix;
    int x, y;

    if (i < fm->row * fm->ncol || i >= fm->row * fm->ncol + fm->nrow * fm->ncol)
        return;
    pix = (fm->entries[i]->issel ? fm->entries[i]->pix[SEL] : fm->entries[i]->pix[UNSEL]);
    i -= fm->row * fm->ncol;
    x = i % fm->ncol;
    y = (i / fm->ncol) % fm->nrow;
    x *= fm->entryw;
    y *= fm->entryh;
    XCopyArea(dpy, pix, fm->main, dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->entryw, fm->entryh, fm->x0 + x, y);
}

/* commit pixmap into window */
static void
commitdraw(struct FM *fm)
{
    fm->scrolly = fm->row * fm->winh / fm->maxrow + fm->ydiff * fm->scrollh / fm->entryh;
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.scroll[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->scroll, dc.gc, 0, 0, config.scroll_pixels, fm->winh);
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.scroll[COLOR_FG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->scroll, dc.gc, 0, fm->scrolly, config.scroll_pixels, fm->scrollh);

    XCopyArea(dpy, fm->main, fm->win, dc.gc, 0, fm->ydiff, fm->winw, fm->winh, 0, 0);
    XCopyArea(dpy, fm->scroll, fm->win, dc.gc, 0, 0, config.scroll_pixels, fm->winh, fm->winw, 0);
}

/* check if we can break line at the given character (is space, hyphen, etc) */
static int
isbreakable(char c)
{
    return c == '.' || c == '-' || c == '_';
}

/* draw names below thumbnail on its pixmaps */
static void
drawentry(struct FM *fm, struct Entry *ent)
{
    XftDraw *draw;
    int x0, x1, prevw, textw0, textw1, prevlen, len0, len1, i;

    textw1 = textw0 = len0 = len1 = 0;
    do {
        prevw = textw0;
        prevlen = len0;
        for (; ent->name[len0] != '\0' && !isspace(ent->name[len0]) && !isbreakable(ent->name[len0]); len0++)
            ;
        textw0 = drawtext(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, ent->name, len0);
        while (isspace(ent->name[len0]) || isbreakable(ent->name[len0]))
            len0++;
    } while (textw0 < fm->textw && ent->name[len0] != '\0' && prevw != textw0);
    if (textw0 >= fm->textw) {
        len0 = prevlen;
        textw0 = prevw;
    }
    while (len0 > 0 && isbreakable(ent->name[len0 - 1]))
        len0--;
    i = len0;
    while (len0 > 0 && isspace(ent->name[len0 - 1]))
        len0--;
    if (i > 0 && ent->name[i] != '\0') {
        len1 = strlen(ent->name+i);
        textw1 = drawtext(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, ent->name + i, len1);
    } else {
        len0 = strlen(ent->name);
        textw0 = drawtext(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, ent->name, len0);
    }

    x0 = fm->textx + max(0, (fm->textw - textw0) / 2);
    x1 = fm->textx + max(0, (fm->textw - textw1) / 2);

    draw = XftDrawCreate(dpy, ent->pix[UNSEL], visual, colormap);
    drawtext(draw, &dc.normal[COLOR_FG], x0, fm->texty0, fm->textw, ent->name, len0);
    if (i > 0 && ent->name[i] != '\0')
        drawtext(draw, &dc.normal[COLOR_FG], x1, fm->texty1, fm->textw, ent->name + i, len1);
    XftDrawDestroy(draw);
    ent->line[0].x = x0;
    ent->line[0].w = textw0;

    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.select[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, ent->pix[SEL], dc.gc, x0, fm->texty0, textw0, dc.fonth);
    draw = XftDrawCreate(dpy, ent->pix[SEL], visual, colormap);
    drawtext(draw, &dc.select[COLOR_FG], x0, fm->texty0, fm->textw, ent->name, len0);
    if (i > 0 && ent->name[i] != '\0') {
        XFillRectangle(dpy, ent->pix[SEL], dc.gc, x1, fm->texty1, textw1, dc.fonth);
        drawtext(draw, &dc.select[COLOR_FG], x1, fm->texty1, fm->textw, ent->name + i, len1);
    }
    ent->line[1].x = x1;
    ent->line[1].w = textw1;

    XftDrawDestroy(draw);

    ent->drawn = 1;
}

/* draw entries on main window */
static void
drawentries(struct FM *fm)
{
    int i, n;

    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.normal[COLOR_BG].pixel);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, fm->main, dc.gc, 0, 0, fm->winw, fm->nrow * fm->entryh);
    n = min(fm->nentries, fm->row * fm->ncol + fm->nrow * fm->ncol);
    for (i = fm->row * fm->ncol; i < n; i++) {
        if (!fm->entries[i]->drawn)
            drawentry(fm, fm->entries[i]);
        copyentry(fm, i);
    }
    commitdraw(fm);
}

/* fork process that get thumbnail */
static int
forkthumb(const char *name)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "./%s", name);
    epipe(fd);
    if ((pid = efork()) > 0) {      /* parent */
        close(fd[1]);
        return fd[0];
    } else {                        /* children */
        close(fd[0]);
        if (fd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO)
            edup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        eexec(config.thumbnailer, path);
    }
    return -1;
}

/* read image path from file descriptor and open image; return its size on *w and *h */
static Imlib_Image
openimg(int fd, int *w, int *h)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int len;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    if ((fp = fdopen(fd, "r")) == NULL) {
        warn("fdopen");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) == NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    len = strlen(path);
    if (path[len - 1] == '\n')
        path[len - 1] = '\0';
    return loadimg(path, config.thumbsize_pixels, w, h);
}

/* scroll list by manipulating scroll bar with pointer; return 1 if fm->row changes */
static int
scroll(struct FM *fm, int y)
{
    int prevrow;
    int half;

    prevrow = fm->row;
    half = fm->scrollh / 2;
    y = max(half, min(y, fm->winh - half));
    y -= half;
    fm->row =  y * fm->maxrow / fm->winh;
    fm->ydiff = (y - fm->row * fm->winh / fm->maxrow) * fm->entryh / fm->scrollh;
    if (fm->row >= fm->maxrow - 1) {
        fm->row = fm->maxrow - 1;
        fm->ydiff = 0;
    }
    return prevrow != fm->row;
}

/* grab pointer and handle scrollbar dragging with the left mouse button */
static void
grabscroll(struct FM *fm, int y)
{
    XEvent ev;
    int dy;

    if (grabpointer(fm, Button1MotionMask) == -1)
        return;
    dy = between(y, fm->scrolly, fm->scrolly + fm->scrollh) ? fm->scrolly + fm->scrollh / 2 - y : 0;
    if (scroll(fm, y + dy))
        drawentries(fm);
    commitdraw(fm);
    while (!XMaskEvent(dpy, ButtonReleaseMask | Button1MotionMask | ExposureMask, &ev)) {
        switch (ev.type) {
        case Expose:
            if (ev.xexpose.count == 0)
                commitdraw(fm);
            break;
        case MotionNotify:
            if (scroll(fm, ev.xbutton.y + dy))
                drawentries(fm);
            commitdraw(fm);
            break;
        case ButtonRelease:
            ungrab();
            return;
        }
    }
}

/* mark or unmark entry as selected */
static void
selectentry(struct FM *fm, struct Entry *ent, int select)
{
    if ((ent->issel != 0) == (select != 0))
        return;
    if (select) {
        ent->snext = fm->selected;
        ent->sprev = NULL;
        if (fm->selected)
            fm->selected->sprev = ent;
        fm->selected = ent;
    } else {
        if (ent->snext)
            ent->snext->sprev = ent->sprev;
        if (ent->sprev)
            ent->sprev->snext = ent->snext;
        else if (fm->selected == ent)
            fm->selected = ent->snext;
        ent->sprev = ent->snext = NULL;
    }
    ent->issel = select;
}

/* mark or unmark entry as selected */
static void
selectentries(struct FM *fm, int a, int b, int select)
{
    int min;
    int max;
    int i;

    if (a == -1 || b == -1)
        return;
    if (a < b) {
        min = a;
        max = b;
    } else {
        min = b;
        max = a;
    }
    for (i = min; i >= 0 && i <= max; i++) {
        selectentry(fm, fm->entries[i], select);
    }
}

/* change directory, reset fd of thumbnailer and index of entry whose thumbnail is being read */
static void
diropen(struct FM *fm, const char *path, int *fd, int *thumbi, int savecwd)
{
    while (fm->selected)
        selectentry(fm, fm->selected, 0);
    if (path == NULL || wchdir(path) != -1) {
        if (*thumbi != -1 && *fd != -1) {       /* close current thumbnailer fd and wait for it */
            close(*fd);
            wait(NULL);
            *thumbi = -1;
        }
        listentries(fm, savecwd);
        calcsize(fm, -1, -1);
        fm->row = 0;
        fm->ydiff = 0;
        *thumbi = 0;
        *fd = forkthumb(fm->entries[*thumbi]->name);
    }
}

/* open file using config.opener */
static void
fileopen(struct Entry *ent)
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int fd;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "./%s", ent->name);
    if ((pid1 = efork()) == 0) {
        if ((pid2 = efork()) == 0) {
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            fd = open(DEV_NULL, O_RDWR);
            edup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd);
            eexec(config.opener, path);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
}

/* go back (< 0) in cwd history; return nonzero when changing directory */
static int
navhistory(struct FM *fm, int *fd, int *thumbi, int dir)
{
    struct Histent *h;

    h = (dir == BACK) ? fm->curr->prev : fm->curr->next;
    if (h == NULL)
        return 0;
    diropen(fm, h->cwd, fd, thumbi, 0);
    fm->curr = h;
    return 1;
}

/* process X11 and poll events */
static void
runevent(struct FM *fm, struct pollfd pfd[], int *thumbi)
{
    static int lastent = -1;        /* index of last clicked entry; -1 if none */
    static Time lasttime = 0;
    struct Entry *ent;
    XEvent ev;
    Imlib_Image img;
    int setlastent;
    int i;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    if (pfd[POLL_STDIN].revents & POLLHUP)
        return;
    if (pfd[POLL_STDIN].revents & POLLIN) {
        // TODO;
    }
    if (pfd[POLL_THUMB].revents & POLLIN) {
        ent = fm->entries[*thumbi];
        img = openimg(pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd, &ent->thumb.w, &ent->thumb.h);
        close(pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd);
        wait(NULL);
        if (img != NULL) {
            drawthumb(fm, img, &ent->thumb, ent->pix);
            copyentry(fm, *thumbi);
            if (*thumbi >= fm->row * fm->ncol && *thumbi < fm->row * fm->ncol + fm->nrow * fm->ncol) {
                commitdraw(fm);
            }
        }
        if (*thumbi != -1 && ++(*thumbi) < fm->nentries) {
            pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd = forkthumb(fm->entries[*thumbi]->name);
        } else {
            pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd = -1;
            *thumbi = -1;
        }
    }
    while (XPending(dpy) && !XNextEvent(dpy, &ev)) {
        setlastent = 1;
        if (ev.type == ClientMessage && (Atom)ev.xclient.data.l[0] == atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW]) {
            /* file manager window was closed */
            running = 0;
            break;
        } else if (ev.type == Expose && ev.xexpose.count == 0) {
            /* window was exposed; redraw its content */
            commitdraw(fm);
        } else if (ev.type == ConfigureNotify) {
            /* file manager window was (possibly) resized */
            calcsize(fm, ev.xconfigure.width, ev.xconfigure.height);
            if (fm->row >= fm->maxrow)
                fm->row = fm->maxrow - 1;
            drawentries(fm);
            commitdraw(fm);
        } else if (ev.type == ButtonPress && (ev.xbutton.button == Button4 || ev.xbutton.button == Button5)) {
            /* mouse wheel was scrolled */
            if (scroll(fm, fm->scrolly + fm->scrollh / 2 + (ev.xbutton.button == Button4 ? -5 : +5)))
                drawentries(fm);
            commitdraw(fm);
        } else if (ev.type == ButtonPress && (ev.xbutton.button == BUTTON8 || ev.xbutton.button == BUTTON9)) {
            /* navigate through history with mouse back/forth buttons */
            if (navhistory(fm, &pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd, thumbi, (ev.xbutton.button == BUTTON8) ? BACK : FORTH)) {
                drawentries(fm);
                commitdraw(fm);
            }
        } else if (ev.type == ButtonPress && ev.xbutton.button == Button1 && ev.xbutton.x > fm->winw) {
            /* scrollbar was manipulated */
            grabscroll(fm, ev.xbutton.y);
        } else if (ev.type == ButtonPress && ev.xbutton.button == Button1) {
            /* mouse left button was pressed */
            if (!(ev.xbutton.state & (ControlMask | ShiftMask)))
                while (fm->selected)
                    selectentry(fm, fm->selected, 0);
            i = getentry(fm, ev.xbutton.x, ev.xbutton.y);
            if (ev.xbutton.state & ShiftMask)
                selectentries(fm, i, lastent, 1);
            else if (i != -1)
                selectentry(fm, fm->entries[i], (ev.xbutton.state & ControlMask) ? !fm->entries[i]->issel : 1);
            if (!(ev.xbutton.state & (ControlMask | ShiftMask)) && i != -1 &&
                i == lastent && ev.xbutton.time - lasttime <= DOUBLECLICK) {
                ent = fm->entries[i];
                if (ent->isdir) {
                    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "./%s", ent->name);
                    diropen(fm, path, &pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd, thumbi, 1);
                    setlastent = 0;
                } else {
                    fileopen(ent);
                }
            }
            drawentries(fm);
            commitdraw(fm);
            lastent = (setlastent) ? i : -1;
            lasttime = ev.xbutton.time;
        }
    }
}

/* clean up drawing context */
static void
cleandc(void)
{
    size_t i;

    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.normal[COLOR_BG]);
    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.normal[COLOR_FG]);
    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.select[COLOR_BG]);
    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.select[COLOR_FG]);
    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.scroll[COLOR_BG]);
    XftColorFree(dpy, visual, colormap, &dc.scroll[COLOR_FG]);
    XFreeGC(dpy, dc.gc);
    for (i = 0; i < dc.nfonts; i++)
        XftFontClose(dpy, dc.fonts[i]);
    free(dc.fonts);
}

/* xfiles: X11 file manager */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct pollfd pfd[POLL_LAST];
    struct FM fm;
    int thumbi = -1;        /* index of current thumbnail, -1 if no thumbnail is being read */
    char *path;
    char *xrm;

    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") || !XSupportsLocale())
        warnx("warning: no locale support");
    if ((dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL)
        errx(1, "could not open display");
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    visual = DefaultVisual(dpy, screen);
    depth = DefaultDepth(dpy, screen);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    colormap = DefaultColormap(dpy, screen);

    XrmInitialize();
    if ((xrm = XResourceManagerString(dpy)) != NULL && (xdb = XrmGetStringDatabase(xrm)) != NULL)
        parseresources();
    parseenviron();
    path = parseoptions(argc, argv);

    imlib_set_cache_size(2048 * 1024);
    imlib_context_set_dither(1);
    imlib_context_set_display(dpy);
    imlib_context_set_visual(visual);
    imlib_context_set_colormap(colormap);

    initsignal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    initatoms();
    initdc();
    initfm(&fm, argc, argv);
    initellipsis();

    memset(pfd, 0, sizeof pfd);
    pfd[POLL_STDIN].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    pfd[POLL_X11].fd = XConnectionNumber(dpy);
    pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd = -1;
    pfd[POLL_STDIN].events = pfd[POLL_X11].events = pfd[POLL_THUMB].events = POLLIN;
    esetcloexec(pfd[POLL_X11].fd);

    diropen(&fm, path, &pfd[POLL_THUMB].fd, &thumbi, 1);
    drawentries(&fm);

    XMapWindow(dpy, fm.win);

    while (running && (XPending(dpy) || poll(pfd, POLL_LAST, -1) != -1))
        runevent(&fm, pfd, &thumbi);

    cleandc();

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

`xfiles.h`:

```
#define ELLIPSIS     "…"
#define CLASS        "XFiles"
#define TITLE        "XFiles"
#define THUMBBORDER  3          /* thumbnail border (for highlighting) */
#define DOUBLECLICK  250
#define DEV_NULL     "/dev/null"
#define DOTDOT       ".."

/* poll entries */
enum {
    POLL_STDIN,
    POLL_X11,
    POLL_THUMB,
    POLL_LAST,
};

/* fg and bg colors */
enum {
    COLOR_FG,
    COLOR_BG,
    COLOR_LAST
};

/* atoms */
enum {
    UTF8_STRING,
    WM_DELETE_WINDOW,
    _NET_WM_NAME,
    _NET_WM_PID,
    _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE,
    _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL,
    ATOM_LAST,
};

/* unselected and selected pixmaps */
enum {
    UNSEL = 0,
    SEL = 1,
    PIX_LAST = 2,
};

/* history navigation direction */
enum {
    BACK,
    FORTH,
};

/* extra mouse buttons, not covered by XLIB */
enum {
    BUTTON8 = 8,
    BUTTON9 = 9,
};

/* working directory history entry */
struct Histent {
    struct Histent *prev, *next;
    char *cwd;
};

/* position and size of a rectangle */
struct Rect {
    int x, y, w, h;
};

/* horizontal position and size of a line segment */
struct Line {
    int x, w;
};

/* file manager */
struct FM {
    struct Entry **entries; /* array of pointer to entries */
    struct Entry *selected; /* list of selected entries */
    struct Rect dirrect;    /* size and position of default thumbnail for directories */
    struct Rect filerect;   /* size and position of default thumbnail for files */
    struct Histent *hist;   /* cwd history; pointer to last cwd history entry */
    struct Histent *curr;   /* current point in history */
    Window win;             /* main window */
    Pixmap main, scroll;    /* pixmap for main window and scroll bar */
    Pixmap dir[PIX_LAST];   /* default pixmap for directories thumbnails */
    Pixmap file[PIX_LAST];  /* default pixmap for file thumbnails */
    int capacity;           /* capacity of entries */
    int nentries;           /* number of entries */
    int row;                /* index of first visible column */
    int ydiff;              /* how much the icons are scrolled up */
    int winw, winh;         /* size of main window */
    int thumbx, thumby;     /* position of thumbnail from entry top left corner */
    int x0;                 /* position of first entry */
    int entryw, entryh;     /* size of each entry */
    int scrollh, scrolly;   /* size and position of scroll bar handle */
    int textw;              /* width of each file name */
    int textx;              /* position of each name from entry top left corner */
    int texty0, texty1;     /* position of each line from entry top left corner */
    int ncol, nrow;         /* number of columns and rows visible at a time */
    int maxrow;             /* maximum value fm->row can scroll */
};

/* directory entry */
struct Entry {
    struct Entry *sprev;    /* for the linked list of selected entries */
    struct Entry *snext;    /* for the linked list of selected entries */
    struct Rect thumb;      /* position and size of the thumbnail */
    struct Line line[2];    /* position and size of both text lines */
    Pixmap pix[PIX_LAST];   /* unselected and selected content of the widget */
    int issel;              /* whether entry is selected */
    int isdir;              /* whether entry is a directory */
    int drawn;              /* whether unsel and sel pixmaps were drawn */
    char *name;             /* file name */
};

/* draw context */
struct DC {
    GC gc;
    XftColor normal[COLOR_LAST];
    XftColor select[COLOR_LAST];
    XftColor scroll[COLOR_LAST];
    FcPattern *pattern;
    XftFont **fonts;
    size_t nfonts;
    int fonth;
};

/* configuration */
struct Config {
    const char *thumbnailer;
    const char *opener;

    const char *dirthumb_path;
    const char *filethumb_path;

    const char *font;
    const char *background_color;
    const char *foreground_color;
    const char *selbackground_color;
    const char *selforeground_color;
    const char *scrollbackground_color;
    const char *scrollforeground_color;

    int thumbsize_pixels;   /* size of icons and thumbnails */
    int scroll_pixels;      /* scroll bar width */
    int width_pixels;       /* initial window width */
    int height_pixels;      /* initial window height */
    int hide;               /* whether to hide .* entries */
};

/* ellipsis size and font structure */
struct Ellipsis {
    char *s;
    size_t len;     /* length of s */
    int width;      /* size of ellipsis string */
    XftFont *font;  /* font containing ellipsis */
};
```

Comment: Why did you choose to write a program using Xlib, when X11 (while still perfectly usable IMO), is planned to be phased out in favor of Wayland? Why not use a widget toolkit that avoids depending on any underlying display protocol?

Comment: @G.Sliepen I use OpenBSD, which has no Wayland support, so X11 is the only way to go.  On not using a toolkit, I am used to xlib; I have even written other utilities in xlib, such as a window manager, so I have more familiarity with xlib than with any toolkit.

Comment: Fair enough, but just know that it will limit (future) portability.